# How to deploy Shopware 6 DB settings from the local to prod environment?

Tags: shopware6

For instance I've added a new custom field on my local environment and now I want to deploy this to Production environment, or I add a new customer role, or change Maximum quantity on the cart settings form. I do not know how to deploy such changes within code, so I want to have them in a repo.
I'm using platform.sh for hosting my project.

I tried to use different commands like `bin/console config:dump-reference`, but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

For syncing the system config you could use [shopware-cli](https://sw-cli.fos.gg/install/) to [pull and push config settings](https://sw-cli.fos.gg/commands/project/#shopware-cli-project-config-pull).

Syncing custom fields could be done by writing a script using the admin-api to [fetch custom fields](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/2aa8ef9af1055-list-with-basic-information-of-custom-field-resources) and their [sets](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/545e3e010efac-list-with-basic-information-of-custom-field-set-resources) from one instance and [persist](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/65158a503cd14-create-a-new-custom-field-resources) them to another one. However if both instances are already out of sync, you will probably have to write a little bit of additional code that checks if custom fields already exist via the technical name. Otherwise you'll be persisting duplicates.